How do I install the "mixer" package in R?
I'm trying to install the "mixer" package (version 1.9, not available at CRAN but available at link) in R. I've tried using the R versions 4.3.0 and 4.2.0, but I get the following error in both cases:
* installing *source* package 'mixer' ...
** package 'mixer' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Barycenters.cc -o Barycenters.o
Barycenters.cc: In member function 'void ermg::Barycenters::initFromClass(const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&)':
Barycenters.cc:91:12: warning: variable 'ind1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   91 |     int s, ind1, ind2;
      |            ^~~~
Barycenters.cc: In member function 'void ermg::Barycenters::kmeansUpdate(int, int)':
Barycenters.cc:122:30: warning: variable 'ind1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  122 |     int s = _Xadj[i].size(), ind1, ind2;
      |                              ^~~~
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Em.cc -o Em.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c EmCore.cc -o EmCore.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Emd.cc -o Emd.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Ermg.cc -o Ermg.o
In file included from ./Barycenters.h:36,
                 from ./Ermg.h:38,
                 from Ermg.cc:20:
./SparseMatrix.h: In instantiation of 'void ermg::SparseMatrix<Content, Container>::laplacianMatrixProduct(double*, double*) [with Content = int; Container = std::vector<int>]':
./SparseMatrix.h:346:4:   required from 'std::vector<double>& ermg::SparseMatrix<Content, Container>::secondEigenVector() [with Content = int; Container = std::vector<int>]'
Ermg.cc:267:52:   required from here
./SparseMatrix.h:87:6: warning: variable 'ind1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   87 |  int ind1=-1, ind2;
      |      ^~~~
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Graph.cc -o Graph.o
Graph.cc: In member function 'std::vector<std::vector<int> > ermg::Graph::getMatrix()':
Graph.cc:45:9: warning: variable 'previd' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   45 |     int previd = 0;
      |         ^~~~~~
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c GraphReader.cc -o GraphReader.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ModelDesigner.cc -o ModelDesigner.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ModelImprover.cc -o ModelImprover.o
ModelImprover.cc: In member function 'void ermg::ModelImprover::improveLikelihoodsSpeed(ermg::EmCore&)':
ModelImprover.cc:212:33: warning: 'kselect' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  212 |    &&(_imove_usedtosplit[kselect-1] == _imove[kselect-1]) ){
      |                          ~~~~~~~^~
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c OCEm.cc -o OCEm.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c OEm.cc -o OEm.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c SOCEm.cc -o SOCEm.o
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c VEstep_R.cc -o VEstep_R.o
In file included from VEstep_R.cc:7:
matrix.h:43:20: warning: 'not_implemented' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   43 | static const char *not_implemented = "Not yet implemented";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:42:20: warning: 'not_square_matrix' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   42 | static const char *not_square_matrix = "Not a squared Matrix";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:41:20: warning: 'out_of_dims' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   41 | static const char *out_of_dims     = "Index out of matrix dimensions";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:40:20: warning: 'not_scalar' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   40 | static const char *not_scalar      = "Matrix can't be trasformed to scalar";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:39:20: warning: 'not_dims_match' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   39 | static const char *not_dims_match  = "Matrix dimensions don't match";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:38:20: warning: 'not_same_dims' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   38 | static const char *not_same_dims   = "Matrix don't have the same dimensions";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from matrix.h:33,
                 from VEstep_R.cc:7:
util.h:48:20: warning: 'str_ctxt' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   48 | static const char *str_ctxt = "Matrix";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
util.h:47:12: warning: 'Msg_level' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   47 | static int Msg_level = 1;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
g77 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls    -O2 -march=native -c dasum.f -o dasum.o
make: g77: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:276: dasum.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mixer'
* removing 'C:/Users/maris/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/mixer'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/maris/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpC8Ox0s/mixer_1.9.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I have also installed "RTools" and "devtools", but nothing worked.
Is there any other way I could install this package? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Perhaps try contacting the maintainer (Pierre Latouche pierre.latouche@univ-paris1.fr)

I had a similar error with a different package a while ago. I forget the exact details but the problem was due to a compiler issue. This post may be relevant.

Are you sure that the correct version of  rtools is installed and in your path so that it  can be found?
